# How do I suppress UTF-8 warnings in Perl?

Tags: perl, utf-8

Due to various reasons I'm getting the error messages `Malformed UTF-8 character` and 
`Wide character in print` from a legacy script.

I would like to suppress/disable those two warnings so that they are not written to `STDERR`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
no warnings 'utf8';
```

But it's best to figure out why you're getting the warning and fix the underlying problem.  Those two warnings indicate something is going wrong in your script.  Suppressing the warnings won't fix the error.

Answer (score 13):

Presumably you are working in utf8.  You have to turn on utf8 handling for each filehandle.

```
binmode STDERR, ":encoding(utf8)";
```

You can do this for all the standard handles with `use open ":encoding(utf8)"`.  See [open](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?open) for more info.

Finally, you can utf8-ify everything, your code, your filehandles and your arguments, with [utf8::all](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?utf8::all).

**Note** that `:utf8` turns on utf8 handling but `:encoding(utf8)` checks the data is valid utf8, so it is safer.  See `perldoc -f binmode` for details.

Answer (score 6):

Here's two examples to help you understand the errors:

```
milu@ubuntu: ~/Milu/Dev/Perl > cat malformed-utf8-char.pl 
use utf8; # script source must be in UTF-8
use strict;
use warnings;
print "K�se\n";
milu@ubuntu: ~/Milu/Dev/Perl > perl malformed-utf8-char.pl
Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected non-continuation byte 0x73,
immediately after start byte 0xe4) at malformed-utf8-char.pl line 4.
Kse
```

The source is in Latin-1, my terminal is in UTF-8. The string is actually "Käse". The `utf8` pragma must either be removed, or the source be saved in UTF-8.

```
milu@ubuntu: ~/Milu/Dev/Perl > cat wide-char-in-print.pl 
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
# binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
print "Группа сайтов РИА Новости\n";
milu@ubuntu: ~/Milu/Dev/Perl > perl wide-char-in-print.pl
Wide character in print at wide-char-in-print.pl line 5.
Группа сайтов РИА Новости
```

The source contains Cyrillic characters, hence the `utf8` pragma is in order. To print those characters to the terminal, however, `STDOUT` must also be set to UTF-8, which you can achieve by calling `binmode`. If you don't do this, a warning is triggered as a wide (Unicode beyond 0x255) character doesn't fit through a narrow (byte) output channel. It'll still look correct, because Perl will just output the bytes as they are, which then happens to look correct.

Comment: in my opinion this is the best answer because instead of telling new programmers how to turn off the 'annoying' warning, which you should not do if you don't understand why you are getting them, it tells you how to prevent getting that warning in the first place. Most warnings are there to help you fix a problem on your side. I heard somewhere that 99.999% of the time, the programmer, not the computer/compiler/interpreter is the problem. It's easy to shut off this warning, but to be in the habit of just closing off annoyances is a bad one to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with debug output from log4perl using Perl on Windows Powershell Console

```
Wide character in print at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Log/Log4perl/Appender/Screen.pm line 39.
```

The solutions was (in the log4perl config file)

```
log4perl.appender.Screen.utf8 = 1
```